# Accessing Bugzilla return internal server error

Tags: perl, 500-error, bugzilla

I tried to install Bugzilla 4.2.1 to an Amazon EC2 with Amazon Linux OS.

I have installed all the necessary perl_modules from the EPEL repo, and configured httpd and mysqld.

But when I try to view it in browser, it throws an internal server error.

Error_log says:

```
The /var/www/html/bugzilla/data/params file does not exist. You probably need to run checksetup.pl. at /var/www/html/bugzilla/Bugzilla/Config.pm line 337.
```

checksetup.pl output:

```
* This is Bugzilla 4.2.1 on perl 5.10.1
* Running on Linux 3.2.18-1.26.6.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 24 02:36:39 UTC 2012

Checking perl modules...
Checking for               CGI.pm (v3.51)     ok: found v3.59 
Checking for           Digest-SHA (any)       ok: found v5.47 
Checking for             TimeDate (v2.21)     ok: found v2.22 
Checking for             DateTime (v0.28)     ok: found v0.74 
Checking for    DateTime-TimeZone (v0.71)     ok: found v1.46 
Checking for                  DBI (v1.41)     ok: found v1.609 
Checking for     Template-Toolkit (v2.22)     ok: found v2.24 
Checking for           Email-Send (v2.00)     ok: found v2.198 
Checking for           Email-MIME (v1.904)    ok: found v1.910 
Checking for                  URI (v1.37)     ok: found v1.40 
Checking for       List-MoreUtils (v0.22)     ok: found v0.33 
Checking for    Math-Random-ISAAC (v1.0.1)    ok: found v1.004 

Checking available perl DBD modules...
Checking for               DBD-Pg (v1.45)     not found 
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.013 
Checking for           DBD-SQLite (v1.29)     not found 
Checking for           DBD-Oracle (v1.19)     not found 

The following Perl modules are optional:
Checking for                   GD (v1.20)     not found 
Checking for                Chart (v2.1)      not found 
Checking for          Template-GD (any)       not found 
Checking for           GDTextUtil (any)       not found 
Checking for              GDGraph (any)       not found 
Checking for           MIME-tools (v5.406)    not found 
Checking for          libwww-perl (any)       not found 
Checking for             XML-Twig (any)       not found 
Checking for          PatchReader (v0.9.6)    not found 
Checking for            perl-ldap (any)       not found 
Checking for          Authen-SASL (any)       not found 
Checking for           RadiusPerl (any)       not found 
Checking for            SOAP-Lite (v0.712)    not found 
Checking for             JSON-RPC (any)       not found 
Checking for              JSON-XS (v2.0)      not found 
Checking for           Test-Taint (any)       not found 
Checking for          HTML-Parser (v3.40)     not found 
Checking for        HTML-Scrubber (any)       not found 
Checking for               Encode (v2.21)     ok: found v2.35 
Checking for        Encode-Detect (any)       not found 
Checking for Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper (any)       not found 
Checking for          Email-Reply (any)       not found 
Checking for          TheSchwartz (any)       not found 
Checking for       Daemon-Generic (any)       not found 
Checking for             mod_perl (v1.999022) ok: found v2.000004 
Version string '0.97-rc1' contains invalid data; ignoring: '-rc1' at Bugzilla/Install/Requirements.pm line 676.
Checking for     Apache-SizeLimit (v0.96)     ok: found v0.97 
Checking for          mod_headers (any)       ok 
Checking for          mod_expires (any)       ok 
Checking for              mod_env (any)       ok 
***********************************************************************
* OPTIONAL MODULES                                                    *
***********************************************************************
* Certain Perl modules are not required by Bugzilla, but by           *
* installing the latest version you gain access to additional         *
* features.                                                           *
*                                                                     *
* The optional modules you do not have installed are listed below,    *
* with the name of the feature they enable. Below that table are the  *
* commands to install each module.                                    *
***********************************************************************
*                    MODULE NAME * ENABLES FEATURE(S)                 *
***********************************************************************
*                             GD * Graphical Reports, New Charts, Old Charts *
*                          Chart * New Charts, Old Charts             *
*                    Template-GD * Graphical Reports                  *
*                     GDTextUtil * Graphical Reports                  *
*                        GDGraph * Graphical Reports                  *
*                     MIME-tools * Move Bugs Between Installations    *
*                    libwww-perl * Automatic Update Notifications     *
*                       XML-Twig * Move Bugs Between Installations, Automatic Update Notifications *
*                    PatchReader * Patch Viewer                       *
*                      perl-ldap * LDAP Authentication                *
*                    Authen-SASL * SMTP Authentication                *
*                     RadiusPerl * RADIUS Authentication              *
*                      SOAP-Lite * XML-RPC Interface                  *
*                       JSON-RPC * JSON-RPC Interface                 *
*                        JSON-XS * Make JSON-RPC Faster               *
*                     Test-Taint * JSON-RPC Interface, XML-RPC Interface *
*                    HTML-Parser * More HTML in Product/Group Descriptions *
*                  HTML-Scrubber * More HTML in Product/Group Descriptions *
*                  Encode-Detect * Automatic charset detection for text attachments *
* Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper * Inbound Email                      *
*                    Email-Reply * Inbound Email                      *
*                    TheSchwartz * Mail Queueing                      *
*                 Daemon-Generic * Mail Queueing                      *
***********************************************************************
COMMANDS TO INSTALL OPTIONAL MODULES:

             GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD
          Chart: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Chart::Lines
    Template-GD: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Template::Plugin::GD::Image
     GDTextUtil: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Text
        GDGraph: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl GD::Graph
     MIME-tools: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl MIME::Parser
    libwww-perl: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl LWP::UserAgent
       XML-Twig: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl XML::Twig
    PatchReader: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl PatchReader
      perl-ldap: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Net::LDAP
    Authen-SASL: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Authen::SASL
     RadiusPerl: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Authen::Radius
      SOAP-Lite: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl SOAP::Lite
       JSON-RPC: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl JSON::RPC
        JSON-XS: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl JSON::XS
     Test-Taint: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Test::Taint
    HTML-Parser: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl HTML::Parser
  HTML-Scrubber: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl HTML::Scrubber
  Encode-Detect: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Encode::Detect
Email-MIME-Attachment-Stripper: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::MIME::Attachment::Stripper
    Email-Reply: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Email::Reply
    TheSchwartz: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl TheSchwartz
 Daemon-Generic: /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Daemon::Generic


To attempt an automatic install of every required and optional module
with one command, do:

  /usr/bin/perl install-module.pl --all

Reading ./localconfig...

OPTIONAL NOTE: If you want to be able to use the 'difference between two
patches' feature of Bugzilla (which requires the PatchReader Perl module
as well), you should install patchutils from:

    http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/

Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.001)    ok: found v4.013 
Checking for                MySQL (v5.0.15)   ok: found v5.5.20 

/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so: undefined symbol: is_prefix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, not an answer, put here because it seems cruel not to try and help if you aren't certain...

A mismatch between your MySQL version and the version your Perl DBD was compiled against? Seems unlikely, though. Or perhaps you actually need to install the MySQL development packages? But I can't remember needing to on other machines...

Comment: Finally I solved the problem. Your suggestion was right. The problem was with my mysql library and with a perl module.

I had to install mysql-devel and the Bundle::DBD:mysql perl library.

Thanks for the help, it works perfectly!